# Why My Function Not Sending Custom Email?

Tags: magento-1.8, transactional, transactional-mail, send-mail

This is the function that carries out send mail functionality. I am one hundred percent sure that, this method is calling correctly.

```
public function sendMail($data)
{
    try {
        // Gets the current store's id
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

        $templateId = $data['mail_template'];

        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');

        //set receipient address
        $emailInfo->addTo(trim($data['mail_to']));

        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

        // Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(trim($data['mail_from']));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'subject' => trim($data['mail_sub']),
            'content' => trim($data['mail_content'])
        ));
       if ($mailer->send()) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Successfully Email Sent');
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::throwException($e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Please note I didn't get any exception while doing this. Also there is no log errors. When I prints `$mailer` variable (holds the instance of `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer`) just above `send` method, I am getting this as output.

```
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer Object
(
[_emailInfos:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info Object
            (
                [_bccNames:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_bccEmails:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_toNames:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [_toEmails:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => to@gmail.com
                    )

                [_data:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
                [_origData:protected] => 
                [_idFieldName:protected] => 
                [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [sender] => sender@gmail.com
        [store_id] => 0
        [template_id] => send_mail_mailer_mail_template
        [template_params] => Array
            (
                [subject] => Test Subject
                [content] => askldjflkajsdkf asdjfkl asdjfasdklf    sdjklsdjksdjkljsdklfjsd fjklj fkljsakl fdjklsdjklfjasdkljf
            )

    )

[_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
[_origData:protected] => 
[_idFieldName:protected] => 
[_isDeleted:protected] => 
[_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Here you can see that, every value is setting correctly here (AFAIK). But I cant see any mails  received at the email address `to@gmail.com`.

What I have done wrong here ? At least give me some hints in order tackle the real problem. Thanks

### Edit 1

I narrowed down my problem and ended up here `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::isValidForSend()`. This method returns `false` in my case. When I dig more there., I found out that, the line

```
 $this->getTemplateSubject()
```

is responsible for the `false` value. In my initial investigation, this returns `fasle` only if I dont have a subject set with my mail template. But I have subject included in my template like this.

```
 <!--@subject {{var subject}} @-->
```

and I can see this value when print the instance of `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` in its `_data` array as like this.

```
[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [sent_success] => 
        [template_type] => 2
        [template_subject] => {{var subject}}
        [orig_template_variables] => {"store url=\"\"":"Store Url","var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url","var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt","var content":"Email Content"}
        [template_styles] => body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
        [template_text] =>
```

Please note the `template_subject`. Dont know how to go further. If you have any thoughts please share

Comment: This is for future visitors :- Please refer my answer. It is very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Send A Mail Then you have to follow the Steps.

**Step 1:** Create Basic Module and register their Module.

**Step 2:** Then You have to create a `config.xml` and in that you have to register your mail template using below code.`custom_template` this is unique name. this is use to call this mail template.

```
<global>
  <template>
    <email>
        <custom_template  module="gameupload">
            <label>Send mail After Game upload</label>
            <file>gameupload/custom_template.html</file>
            <type>html</type>
        </custom_template>
    </email>
  </template>
</global>
```

**Step 3:** now you  have to create mail template in `app\locale\en_US\template\email\gameupload\custom_template.html`

Type the Below code. where `cmp_name` will passed when you call the template.

```
<h1>Game Upload By {{var cmp_name}}</h1>
```

**Step 4:** Now open your Controller and `sendMail($data)`

```
try {
    // Gets the current store's id
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    /* Code to lode custom email template */

    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('custom_template');

    //Create an array of variables to assign to template
    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
     $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
        $to_email = 'upload@indiemaniagames.com';
        $to_name = 'Hello IndieMania';
        $subject = 'Game Upload By ' . $data['cmp_name'];
        $Body = $processedTemplate;

        $sender_email = $data['email'];
        $sender_name = $data['cmp_name'];
         $mail = new Zend_Mail(); //class for mail
        $mail->setBodyHtml($Body); //for sending message containing html code
        $mail->setFrom($sender_email, $sender_name);
        $mail->addTo($to_email, $to_name);
        //$mail->addCc($cc, $ccname);    //can set cc
        //$mail->addBCc($bcc, $bccname);    //can set bcc
        $mail->setSubject($subject);
        try {
            if ($mail->send()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Successfully Email Sent');
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Email cannot sent');
        }
}
```

This way you can send custom mail as well as passes data form controller to mail Template.

Comment: Thanks Keyul...Every step that you have described here is actually present in my module. The only difference resides in the code that send mail. Let me go through it.

Comment: yes sure go thorough it and let me know if you facing any problem then

Comment: It looks like the function that you have described to send the mail is actually looks same what I have did. Instead of using `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` directly, I just used another wrapper class `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer` which also provide by Magento by default !!!!

Comment: I need to check this thing I always follow this way

Comment: Yup. Now I will try your code instead of mine and let you know the feedback. :-)

Comment: yes sure. :) It will working because each time I am using this

Comment: you can see that I am using a variable in my subject. I am setting it in my code too..Dont know why it fails to load subject !

Comment: http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/ try this one

Comment: I have used your code to send mail. But my real problem was not the code problem. It was a configuration problem. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

My real problem was not the code that I have used to send mail. I dont have `sendmail` enabled in my system and it drops me down actully.

So make sure you have SMTP configurations are configured correctly. If sendmail is not in your system, then install it.

```
 sudo yum install sendmail  -- in fedora
 sudo apt-get sendmail      -- ubuntu
```

If it is installed, just restart it

```
sudo service sendmail restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For more information, [***refer this link***](http://bjarneo.codes/zend_mail_transport_exception-with-message-unable-to-send-mail/)